# ¿Cómo puedo corregir ésta advertencia de matplotlib al realizar un diagrama de tallo?

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, jupyter

Intento representar un diagrama de tall utilizando matplotlib, de la siguiente manera.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = [
    (0, 0.1),
    (1, 0.3),
    (2, 0.3),
    (3, 0.1),
]

labels, y = zip(*data)  # crea un dataframe juntando dos listas.

x = range(len(y))
plt.stem(x, y, linefmt='-', markerfmt='o', basefmt=' ', use_line_collection=False)  # Modificación: uso de parámetros de keyword
plt.xticks(x, labels)
plt.axis([-1, 6, 0, 0.5])
plt.show()
```

Muestra bien el gráfico, pero me devuelve una advertencia que no entiendo bien.

```
/tmp/ipykernel_12880/846626540.py:13: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The 'use_line_collection' parameter of stem() was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.6 and will be removed two minor releases later. If any parameter follows 'use_line_collection', they should be passed as keyword, not positionally.
  plt.stem(x, y, linefmt='-', markerfmt='o', basefmt=' ', use_line_collection=False)  # Modificación: uso de parámetros de keyword
```

¿Qué significa y cómo puedo resolver este contratiempo, sin ignorar las advertencias.? Agradeceŕe ayuda.

Comment: La advertencia es bastante clara, `stem` [no soportará](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/prev_api_changes/api_changes_3.6.0.html#passing-linefmt-positionally-to-stem-is-undeprecated) más `use_line_collection`. Adicional tampoco soportará valores posicionales de formato, [ver uso](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.stem.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.stem). Entonces para quitar la advertencia, por lo pronto elimina `use_line_collection=False` del código.